# How can i migrate from localhost neo4j browser to cloud?

Tags: browser, neo4j, localhost, cloud, bloom

To create my databases, I have set up a *Neo4j desktop* and use a *localhost browser* to query and visualise the results. Would it be possible for me to query and visualise my databases graphs in the *Neo4j browser in the cloud* instead of localhost? To make it more accessible, I need it.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a neo4j AuraDB free instance, then you can connect to it through your local neo4j browser through neo4j desktop:

- create a new project
- click on Add -> remote connection
- insert the credential you got after creating the AuraDB instance
- click connect and open neo4j browser